# Two structurally similar routes - different controllers - second one is never called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi guys I have the following routes defined:

```
  appRouteProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl : '../../app/templates/home.html',
    controller  : 'IndexController'

  }).when('/users/create', {
    templateUrl : '../../app/templates/auth/register.html',
    controller  : 'RegisterController'

  }).when('/users/login', {
    templateUrl : '../../app/templates/auth/login.html',
    controller  : 'LoginController'


  }).when('/posts/:id/:slug', {
    templateUrl : '../../app/templates/posts/single.html',
    controller  : 'PostController',
    resolve:{
      sharedParamsData:function(sharedParams){
        return sharedParams.promise;
      },
    }

  }).when('/:city/:category/:services?', {
    templateUrl : '../../app/templates/container.html',
    controller  : 'VenuesController',
    resolve:{
      sharedParamsData:function(sharedParams){
        return sharedParams.promise;
      },
    }
  }).otherwise( {
    redirect: '/'
  });
```

`SharedParams` is just a service I'm passing however the main issue is with the two routes:

```
/posts/:id/:slug
/:city/:category/:services?
```

If I have a url of the form `/posts/16/this-is-a-post` the first route is never called and instead the second route is called. In the second route I can understand that the `:city` parameter mistakes `/posts` to be a parameter. But I'm defining it as a seperate route. Despite that why isn't the route being called. Please help here.

Comment: You could update your route to `/city/:city/:category/:services?` or that's something you want to avoid?

Comment: Exactly we want these exact same routes - can't have a compromise on the routes here :(

Comment: Have you tried `ui-router` ? I have used like this before in projects, never had any issues. I have these routes in one project `'^/member/edit'` and `'^/member/:id'`

Comment: Ah silly me - I wasnt including the js file which had the PostController defined - included that in my gulpfil and its working :) thanks for the help. I'll take a look at UI-ROUTER as well...